# What's the Best Way to Create a UWP XAML Form to Prompt for Name and Mailing Address?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to create a standard Name and Address form like with multiple textboxs on a line to save space.

Is it better to start with Grids or Stack Panels and nest them?  Is it better to create a custom control that combines TextBox and TextBlock?

I'll post my solution below.  I was just curious if there's a better way to do this and what the merits of each method might be.

```
    <!-- Snipplet of UWP XAML -->
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel Width="400" Background="Aqua" Padding="10"
          BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="First Name"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Last Name"/>

                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="White"
                    Text="John"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" 
                    Text="Smith"/>
            </Grid>

            <TextBlock>Address1</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Background="White" Text="1 Center St"/>

            <TextBlock>Address2:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Background="White"/>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="City"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="State"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Zip"/>

                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="White"
                   Text="Townville"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="White"
                   Text="XX"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Background="White" 
                   Text="12345"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock/>
            <StackPanel 
                   Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <Button Content="Ok" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
                  Width="100" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                <Button Content="Cancel" 
                  Width="100" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can design your control as you want or you can make it separately on a **UserControl** but thing should be need to note here , you already put the text already on textbox instead of using placeholder text , so i change it in your code

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Width="400" Background="Aqua" Padding="10"
      BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="First Name"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Last Name"/>

            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="White"
                PlaceholderText="John"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" 
                PlaceholderText="Smith"/>
        </Grid>

        <TextBlock>Address1</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Background="White" PlaceholderText="1 Center St"/>

        <TextBlock>Address2:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Background="White"/>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="City"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="State"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Zip"/>

            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="White"
               PlaceholderText="Townville"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="White"
               PlaceholderText="XX"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Background="White" 
               PlaceholderText="12345"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock/>
        <StackPanel 
               Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
            <Button Content="Ok" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
              Width="100" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
            <Button Content="Cancel" 
              Width="100" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and you can learn basics of uwp development from this [link](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners-14541)

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of performance, having only one panel is better - see the [UWP app  developer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-your-xaml-layout) on performance. Therefore, I would use a [relative panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RelativePanel), ending up with something like this:

```
<RelativePanel>
    <!-- Horizontal group -->
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBx1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBx2" RelativePanel.RightOf="TxtBx1"/>

    <!-- Below the first group -->

    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBx3" RelativePanel.Below="TxtBx1"/>

    <!-- Another horizontal group -->
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBx4" RelativePanel.Below="TxtBx3"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBx5" RelativePanel.RightOf="TxtBx4"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

But in all honesty, there is no 'correct' answer as such - it depends on what you rank more highly in your app, be it performance or code readability.